# Deploy clojure packages to clojar

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am trying to deploy a package to `clojars`.

When I run `lein deploy clojars` command, I get
following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must provide valid :files to deploy-artifacts
 at cemerick.pomegranate.aether$deploy_artifacts.invokeStatic (aether.clj:346)
    cemerick.pomegranate.aether$deploy_artifacts.doInvoke (aether.clj:312)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:665)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:660)
    cemerick.pomegranate.aether$deploy.invokeStatic (aether.clj:431)
    cemerick.pomegranate.aether$deploy.doInvoke (aether.clj:395)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:1096)
    leiningen.deploy$deploy.invokeStatic (deploy.clj:235)
    leiningen.deploy$deploy.doInvoke (deploy.clj:172)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:470)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:165)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:132)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:705)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:667)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:660)
    leiningen.core.main$partial_task$fn__7330.doInvoke (main.clj:284)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:139)
    clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke (AFunction.java:31)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:667)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:660)
    leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invokeStatic (main.clj:334)
    leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invoke (main.clj:320)
    leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invokeStatic (main.clj:343)
    leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invoke (main.clj:336)
    leiningen.core.main$_main$fn__7419.invoke (main.clj:453)
    leiningen.core.main$_main.invokeStatic (main.clj:442)
    leiningen.core.main$_main.doInvoke (main.clj:439)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:705)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:665)
    clojure.main$main_opt.invokeStatic (main.clj:514)
    clojure.main$main_opt.invoke (main.clj:510)
    clojure.main$main.invokeStatic (main.clj:664)
    clojure.main$main.doInvoke (main.clj:616)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:705)
    clojure.main.main (main.java:40)
```

Not sure whats the requirement around `:files` option.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

### Update

Here is the link to the project https://github.com/ludbek/sql-compose

Comment: Could you please provide provide the project, that shows this problem.

Comment: I have added the link to the project @cfrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed. Not sure what went wrong with lein. Instead of using lein I used `mvn` to deploy the package.

The blog post below was helpful.
https://oli.me.uk/clojure-projects-from-scratch/